# Como aumentar o desempenho de uma busca com for

Tags: python-3.x, desempenho

Basicamente o programa que fiz faz esse mesmo procedimento, porem com mais dados. 
Preciso aumentar o desempenho da busca, claro que isso pode ser feito com bibliotecas caso seja melhor.
Não importa como aumente o desempenho, desde que o formato dos dados se mantenha.

```
import time
import random

numbers = []
searchs = []
search_range = 1

for i in range(0, 9999):
    numbers.append((int(random.random() * 100), int(random.random() * 100), int(random.random() * 100)))
    searchs.append((int(random.random() * 100), int(random.random() * 100), int(random.random() * 100)))

start = time.time()
for search in searchs:
    for number in numbers:
        if (search[0] > (number[0] - search_range) and search[0] < (number[0] + search_range) and
            search[1] > (number[1] - search_range) and search[1] < (number[1] + search_range) and
            search[2] > (number[2] - search_range) and search[2] < (number[2] + search_range)):
            print(number)
            break

print('Time: %.2f' % (time.time() - start))
```

Obs: Lembrando que apenas oque eu quero é o desempenho da busca, o resto do programa foi apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Não resolve o problema, mas torna o código mais pythonico: https://repl.it/repls/ClosedNormalMarmot, no que diz respeito às comparações/intervalos, podes usar também `randint` e escusas de transformar em inteiro

Comment: @Miguel Não sabia que dava pra fazer dessa forma, vou corrigir. E sabe alguma biblioteca que faça buscar dessa forma porem com mais desempenho ??

Comment: Vais ter sempre de comparar cada valor de uma lista com cada valor da outra. Dessa maneira consegui reduzir 2-3secs, não é relevante mas reduz um bocadinho

Comment: @Miguel Pensei que ia ter uma biblioteca para esse tipo de processamento.

Comment: Mais uma otimização: https://repl.it/repls/ClosedNormalMarmot . Ao evitar o print dentro do for interno, e uso de gerador